# Retrieving vocabulary from HashingVectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I was using `tfidfVectorizer` to use tfidf values as weights to convert my word vectors to sentence vectors. Since I ran into memory error , I decided to use `HashingVectorizer` instead. Is there a way to get the vector for a given word in this set-up like with `tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_[word]` ?

Answer (score 2):

`HashingVectorizer` is a stateless transformer. As given in [documentation of `fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.fit):

> ```
> fit(X, y=None)
>     Does nothing: this transformer is stateless.
> ```

This `fit()` method is just for compatibility with other utilities in scikit-learn. `HashingVectorizer` doesnt actually remember anything. So there is no vocabulary. It just gets tokens from the supplied documents and then hashes it to get the columns as defined by `n_features` in constructor:

> ```
> n_features : integer, default=(2 ** 20)
> ```
>
> The number of features (columns) in the output matrices. Small numbers of features are likely to cause hash collisions, but large
>   numbers will cause larger coefficient dimensions in linear learners.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any suggestions to obtain TfIdf without running into memory error and still obtain the vocabulary ?

Comment: @grshankar For that I would need more details. How are you converting word vectors into sentence vectors? When are you running into memory error? The code you are using etc

Comment: I create sentence vectors by weighting word vectors (from Glove) with tfidf values. While I attempt to get tfidf values, the memory error occurs in `tfidf_vect.fit_transform(data)` step